# Xresources not loaded under MATE desktop

Tags: mate

I have colours set for my urxvt terminal in my .Xresources. I know this file works because manually running `xrdb ~/.Xresources` produces the expected result.

I have tried putting `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` EVERYWHERE (`~/.{xprofile,xsession,xsessionrc,xinitrc}`) to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

Use `dconf-editor` (or whatever other xsettings editor you have) to set the attribute `active` to `false` under  `org.mate.SettingsDaemon.plugins.xrdb`.

Your DM should load the `.Xresources` file as a part of its session wrapper. Otherwise add it to your `.xprofile` or `.xsessionrc` on Debian.

**Explanation below:**

So I snapped and replaced my `xrdb` binary with a bash script that logged the calling process, time stamp and arguments to a file.

It showed my `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` actually being executed followed by `mate-settings-daemon`. I verified this with `xrdb -query` which lo and behold actually showed my settings except that background and foreground had been overridden.

So I googled and found the source to mate-settings-daemon: https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-settings-daemon/blob/master/plugins/xrdb/msd-xrdb-manager.c#L which also loads my settings file but then **overrides stuff with theme colours!**

## (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

So `dconf-editor` finds `org.mate.SettingsDaemon.plugins.xrdb` with the attribute `active` setting this to `false` fixes the issue.

Comment: Funny that you put in the leg work for this just today! I just came across this problem in trying to unify my emacs settings across systems with .Xresources. Confirmed it works for both Mate 1.12 and 1.20.